# Get HTML Table Row in Tetboxes for Editing Using JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I am creating an HTML Table through jQuery using this code:

```
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        function createTable() {
            mytable = $('<table></table>').attr({ id: "basicTable" });
                var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(mytable);
                $('<td></td>').text($('#drpEnter').val()).appendTo(row);
                $('<td></td>').text($('#txtAge').val()).appendTo(row);
            mytable.appendTo("#box");
            $('#drpEnter').val(0);
            return false;
        };
    </script>
```

Here "drpEnter" is a drop down, "txtAge" is a textbox and "box" is a div in asp.net as you can see here:

```
    <div id="divTabl">
        Name:
        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpEnter" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Hello" Value="Hello"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Where" Value="Where"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        Age:
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAge"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnclick" runat="server" OnClientClick="return createTable();" Text="Create Table" />
    <div id="box">
    </div>
```

I had called the script function on the click of button, my table is working fine and getting updated with each new click.

Now I want that my table should have an "Edit" and "Delete" button, on click of Edit button age should be displayed in the "txtAge" Textbox from where user can edit it and on  button click Table should get updated, Delete button should delete the particular row. Could anyone help me to achieve this functionality!!

Comment: Have you made an attempt to do this yourself? If so, what specific problem are you having?

Comment: Yes I had tried to do this, but I don't know how to get the value of particular row in Textboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my Question by myself, thanks everyone for not answering because if anyone of you would have provided the answer then I wouldn't have tried this much by myself :)

This is the solution:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('click', '#btnedt', function() {
                debugger;
                $('#drpEnter').val($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text());
                $('#txtAge').val($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text());
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here #btnedt is the dynamic button created by using jquery, this button will be generated with each new row, so updated code for generating Table is as follows:

```
    <script>
        function createTable() {
            mytable = $('<table></table>').attr({ id: "basicTable" });
            if ($('#txtEnter').val() != "") {
                var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(mytable);
                $('<td></td>').text($('#drpEnter').val()).appendTo(row);
                $('<td></td>').text($('#txtAge').val()).appendTo(row);
                $('<td><input type="button" id="btnedt" value="Edit" /></td>').appendTo(row);
            }
            mytable.appendTo("#box");
            $('#drpEnter').val("");
            $('#txtAge').val("");
            return false;
        };
    </script>
```

I hope it will solve someone's problem.